# How to add objects to Sphinx's global index, or cross-reference by alias?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, cross-reference

Each time I have to reference a method I rather not `` :func:`package.subpackage.module.method` ``, especially for frequently used methods. Is there a way to somehow "register" `package.subpackage` so that only `module.method` suffices? (Better yet, `package.subpackage.module`, so `method` suffices, assuming no conflicts).

A solution shouldn't involve adding directories to `package` or `subpackage`, but I'm fine adding whatever to `docs/`. Note that the problem here concerns a `method` defined outside of the docstring's module (otherwise `.method` works).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a simple extension that will resolve the aliases you define. The below example is a short proof of concept for that:

```
# add this to conf.py

from sphinx.addnodes import pending_xref
from sphinx.ext.intersphinx import missing_reference
from docutils.nodes import Text

# alias ref is mapped to a pair (real ref, text to render)
reftarget_aliases = {
    'foo.spam': ('foo.bar.baz.spam', 'spam'),
}


def resolve_intersphinx_aliases(app, env, node, contnode):
    alias = node.get('reftarget', None)
    if alias is not None and alias in reftarget_aliases:
        real_ref, text_to_render = reftarget_aliases[alias]
        # this will resolve the ref
        node['reftarget'] = real_ref

        # this will rewrite the rendered text:
        # find the text node child
        text_node = next(iter(contnode.traverse(lambda n: n.tagname == '#text')))
        # remove the old text node, add new text node with custom text
        text_node.parent.replace(text_node, Text(text_to_render, ''))

        # delegate all the rest of dull work to intersphinx
        return missing_reference(app, env, node, contnode)


def resolve_internal_aliases(app, doctree):
    pending_xrefs = doctree.traverse(condition=pending_xref)
    for node in pending_xrefs:
        alias = node.get('reftarget', None)
        if alias is not None and alias in reftarget_aliases:
            real_ref, text_to_render = reftarget_aliases[alias]
            # this will resolve the ref
            node['reftarget'] = real_ref

            # this will rewrite the rendered text:
            # find the text node child
            text_node = next(iter(node.traverse(lambda n: n.tagname == '#text')))
            # remove the old text node, add new text node with custom text
            text_node.parent.replace(text_node, Text(text_to_render, ''))


def setup(app):
    app.connect('doctree-read', resolve_internal_aliases)
    app.connect('missing-reference', resolve_intersphinx_aliases)
```

Now all refs `` :role:`foo.spam` `` will be replaced with `` :role:`spam <foo.bar.baz.spam>` ``, regardless of the exact role (`class`, `func`, `mod`, whatever). Sure, this is only a draft and untested, but you should get the idea. May be even a good starting point for a new Sphinx extension project :-)

Comment: Looks promising, and the "rename" part does work, but not "retarget"; no hyperlink/cross-reference. I did: `{'Class.method': ('package.subpackage.module.Class.method', 'Class.method')}` - which I presume is the intended use. I'm afraid I can't do much with a "draft" as I'm clueless on `docutils` & the rest, but if you edit a working code, it'll be the exact answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Links for reference to actual project [`reftarget_aliases`](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/dev_tg/blob/master/docs/source/conf.py#L141), 
[docstring](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/dev_tg/blob/master/deeptrain/callbacks.py#L73), 
and [rendered docs](https://dev-tg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deeptrain.html#deeptrain.callbacks.TraingenCallback.on_train_iter_end).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon you're right, this was only part of the solution for intersphinx references -- I misread your question and thought about intersphinx refs for some reason. I've added a similar code for resolving internal refs, the approach is pretty much the same; one could extract the duplicated code in a separate function etc etc. Also, if you don't use intersphinx, you can safely remove the listener on `missing-reference` event and leave only the `doctree-read` one.

Comment: I'll be sharing this - indeed it should be an extension, and once is, we'll be asking "how was this ever NOT a thing".

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I'm not going to monkey-patch my `conf.py` for several reasons. To start with, docutils does not have a full API spec (the section on this says:"todo") which to me reads as "hands-off". Then, you undermine trust creating an unreasonable problem for anyone trying to read your code. Understanding reST&Sphinx is hard enough without docutils. There's no guarantee this won't break your Sphinx, any subsequent bug or error will leave you guessing if the monkey-patch isn't the cause. From an engineering pov this is a bad practice.

Comment: @bad_coder I don't know of its stability, but so far it's worked without issue. On readability, it's easily a net-plus: having to retype "absolute reference path" each time for common classes and methods immensely clutters docstrings. There also isn't a way to show "part of" the full path, unlike now: `ClassName.method`, when it's clear what `ClassName` is - and the absolute path is available on hover / click anyway. Most who even both to read the docs should have little problem with abbrevs in docstrings, and none at all in rendered docs.

Comment: If I have to go for a fully qualified name, I'll try hard to keep it out of the docstring and in the `.rst`. The vanilla syntax is, imho, sufficient :role:'X.Y<.Y>' does a good enough job. (I could not, honestly, ship a monkey patched `conf.py`...)

Comment: @bad_coder writing Sphinx extensions has nothing to do with monkeypatching; check out [Sphinx application API](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html) for available entry points. Also, the `conf.py` should never be distributed and be of any concern to the end user. You have a valid point into passing custom unrelated names as aliases though; e.g. these won't be resolved by IDEs correctly, so should be used with caution.

Comment: @bad_coder However, there's at least one valid use case of aliasing right now as Sphinx can't link reexported objects, using the long import name instead; this is where we rewrite the refs in our projects. This is a long-known issue which was fixed only recently in [#7463](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/7463).

Comment: @hoefling thank you for pointing that out, I appreciate it. Perhaps not a coincidence, I had also thought to mention: the IDE implications...(I'm glad you said it!)

Comment: Thanks @hoefling for this answer which saved me a ton of needless hassle and allowed me to solve some other, seemingly unrelated problems. I made some extensions for my own benefit, which are at: https://github.com/khaeru/genno/blob/692b13ae3a365c18b15df914468ec66da5a94876/doc/conf.py#L147-L210

These include (a) use regular expressions to match a portion or all of the reftarget to be replaced, (b) make the display text change optional, (c) optionally also change the reftype and/or refdomain.

Answer (score 2):

From the moment you can see the class, function or method, in the index you can abreviate the writing of the name.
For example, 
instead of writing the cross-reference with the fully qualified name:

```py
:func:`~package.subpackage.module.method`
:meth:`~package.subpackage.module.method`
```

you can simply write:

```py
:func:`.method`
:meth:`.method`
```

Notice the **use of the dot `.`** is necessary if you are cross-referencing something outside of your local scope. If, for example, you are referencing an attribute or method within the class where you write the cross-reference, then the following does work:

```py
:meth:`method`
:attr:`method`
```

Notice also, that within the scope `:meth:` and `:func:` both work interchangeably. However, outside the scope you have to use the precise role, depending if you are referencing a method, or a function.

Be reminded you can have name collisions, since the same name can be used in different modules for different objects. In that case, you should use the fully qualified name to distinguish exactly which object you are referencing.

It's important to check the index to verify the object has already been inserted there (which is done automatically by the autodoc or domain directives in your `.rst` files). The normal index will display "object name (fully qualified name)", if it's in the index then it can be cross-referenced.

---

**Edit**: below's a workaround to show `.method` as `class.method`; info above applies.

```
`ClassName.`:meth:`.method`
```

[image]

Comment: "so there isn't a way to "index X as Y?" For cross-references in Sphinx, No. Use this, `:meth:'X.Y<.Y>'`